# PHP 7 Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Some2::send() must be an instance of Path\To, instance of Path\To\Some given

Tags: php

I have 3 .php files: some_class.php, some2_class.php and index.php

some_class.php

```
<?php
namespace Path\To;

class Some {
    public $id;
    public function __construct() {
        $this -> id = 2021;
    }
}
```

some2_class.php

```
<?php
class Some2 {
    public function send(\Path\To $some)
    {
        
    }
}
```

index.php

```
require_once('some_class.php');
require_once('some2_class.php');

$c = new Path\To\Some();

$c2 = new Some2();
$c2 -> send($c);
```

And when execute index.php I see:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Some2::send()
> must be an instance of Path\To, instance of Path\To\Some given, called
> in /home/l/liketeks/work/public_html/index.php on line 8 and defined
> in /home/l/liketeks/work/public_html/some2_class.php:3 Stack trace: #0
> /home/l/liketeks/work/public_html/index.php(8):
> Some2->send(Object(Path\To\Some)) #1 {main} thrown in
> /home/l/liketeks/work/public_html/some2_class.php on line 3

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not fix what that message tells you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the full path for the type hint. Shouldn't it be:

```
class Some2 {
    public function send(\Path\To\Some $some)
    {
        
    }
}
```